# How to delete files on the command line with regular expressions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, regex, zsh

Lets say I have 20 files named FOOXX, where XX is the number of the file, eg 01, 02 etc.

At the moment, if I want to delete all files lower than the number 10, this is easy and I just use a wildcard, eg `rm FOO0*`

However, if I want to delete specific files ina  range, eg 13-15, this becomes more difficult.

`rm FOO[13-15]` does not work, and asks me if I wish to delete all files. Likewse `rm FOO1[3-5]` wishes to delete all files that begin with FOO1

So, what is the best way to delete ranges of files like this?

I have tried with both bash and zsh, and I don't think they differ so much for such a basic task?

Comment: "... rm FOO1[3-5] wishes to delete all files that begin with FOO1" This makes no sense, and certainly isn't the case here.

Comment: @Ignacio yeah- I'd like to see the character set has that collation order!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In bash you can use:

```
rm FOO1{3..5}
```

or

```
rm FOO1{3,4,5}
```

to delete FOO13, FOO14 and FOO15.

Bash expansions brace are documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).

Comment: Or even `rm FOO{13..15}`.

Comment: Is this also true for ZSH?

Comment: @Jack: Yes, it is.

Comment: @Jack: `bash` commands form subset of `z` shell commands.

Comment: So I need to learn *both* regex and globbing syntax. Boohoo. :)

Answer (score 13):

For future readers, the `find` command can also delete files. I settled on this for a similar problem:

```
find . -type f -regex '...' -delete
```

but the chosen answer is the simplest anser to this question.

Comment: The chosen answer is only good for files that follow a naming convention though. Thanks to your answer, I could just delete all object files in a directory. (in my case I just went with `find . -name "*.o" -delete` and it worked like a charm)

Answer (score 6):

ls | grep regex | xargs rm

Comment: You should use `find -regex ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` for this, otherwise it fails for filenames with spaces.

Comment: Of course, if you're going to use `find` then you may as well just use `-exec`.

Comment: In my case the files had spaces, and changing the delimiter fixes the spaces issue: ls | grep regex | xargs --delimiter='\n' rm

Comment: -1 for [attempting to parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @evilsoup, +1 for adding that warning, but, who inserts a new line in a file name?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, Shouldn't it be `find . -regex ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` instead?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, How?

Comment: @IulianOnofreiIn GNU `find` the current directory is implied. You can omit the `.`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson So the problem is only on mac, where it throws the error `find: illegal option -- r`.